# При наведении курсора на ссылку рисуются блок вокруг

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть меню:
[image: before]
если курсор навести на ссылку, не нажимая затем отодвинуть, рисуется не понятный блок вокруг ссылки:
[image: after]
если пронести над всеми ссылками получается вообще страх:
[image: after2]
Как избавиться от этих блоков??
Див для этого меню:

Див ссылок:

```css
 .menuCaption {
   padding: 3px;
   font-weight: bold;
 }
 
 a {
   color: orange;
   /* Цвет ссылки */
   text-decoration: none
 }
 
 a:hover {
   color: #f06015;
   /* Цвет ссылки при наведении на нее курсора мыши */
   text-decoration: none
 }
```

```html
<div class="menuCaption">Меню:</div>

<a href="#">1</a>
<br/>
<a href="#">2</a>
<br/>
<a href="#">3</a>
<br/>
<a href="#">4</a>
<br/>
```

Comment: Попробуй добавить outline: none;

Comment: Добавил в css  outline: none;
не помгло

Comment: Добавь в вопрос кусок html для меню.

Comment: Стандартно для ссылки нет такого бордера. У вас где то какой то стиль накладывается. У вас `parent node` для ссылок какой тег стоит? может это из за него. может там стоит `outline` или `border`.

Comment: ..."может там стоит outline или border. –"
не описаны для других свойств css

Answer (score 0):

Такой эффект как я понял наблюдается после долгой работы браузера, после перезапуска Chrome данные ссылки стали отображаться нормально.
Благодарю всех за внимание.